# Is it a good idea to install all things in winetricks?

Tags: wine, winetricks

As known, to run windows programs on wine we usually need to install additional components and stuff to make wine run it.

I'm just thinking, why the pain? winetricks has a list of "libraries" (or whatever), each time I want to run something I need to install some, why not install them all?

or maybe is there a set of instructions or some documentation or so that would tell me to install certain things in winetricks that would make wine run "almost anything" like windows does? Is there a way to "get the best out of wine"?

Answer (score 1):

For the winetricks which provide Windows libraries there is no reason not to, this will indeed make a lot of programs easier to run. But some of the other tricks are instead used to say install MS Office or another specific task, so unless you are installing Office they are useless. The other thing is the winetricks also often use DLLs which are not open source, which takes away from the point of wine as an open source compatibility layer. This is why they do not come as part of wine.

Comment: hey nice to meet you again :D ... I replied to your answer in the question! now is there some list of instructions that would tell me what to install specifically? :D

Comment: run `winetricks dlls list` to get a list of available dlls.